# Modify behaviour of CSS after wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

As you can see the image on the left sticks to the right div, but once the right div wraps and puts under the picture, the image stays on the left. I would like to have the picture and the second div (below, after wrapping) in the same size, just matching the horizontal size. 
(For some reason the picture is not displayed, but it is a 800x500px picture).

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #91897b;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
 background: #ccb288;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #e8aa45;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background: #f4a11a;
}

img {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:500px;
}

.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 background-color: DodgerBlue;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-grow:1;
}

.flex-container > div {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 width:auto;
 height:100%margin: 1px;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.caja-scroll{
 overflow-y:auto;
 background-color:#fafafa;
 border-color: coral;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 max-width:100%;
  max-height:500px;
  flex-shrink:5;
}

.bordes_gallery {
 border-style:solid;
 max-width:100%;
 flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}

.gallery_item {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 max-height:100px;
 border-style:dotted;
}

.gallery_item > #imagen {
 order: 1;
 flex-basis: 100px;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
}

.gallery_item > #texto {
 order: 2;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div style="order: 1; flex-basis: content; align-items:center; justify-content:flex-start; display: flex;">
          <img src="http://kb4images.com/images/usa-wallpaper/36955559-usa-wallpaper.jpg"></img>
        </div>
  
        <div style="order: 2; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 28rem; max-height:500px; justify-content:flex-start; flex-shrink: 0;">
            <div class="caja-scroll">
                <div class="col-md-12 bordes_gallery">
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: becareful about the use of tag. It's not because you want a particular "behavior" that you can use the *behavior* tag which is related to a language:http://people.csail.mit.edu/brooks/papers/AIM-1227.pdf (read the description of tag before using) ... same thing for *flex* and *wrap*

Comment: I know that it is not related to the question, but you made several mistakes in your code. An `id` should only be used once per page, if you have several elements that need the same selector, use a `class` instead. There is a closing `img` tag that should not be there (first image) and you are also missing a closing `div` tag at the end of your code.

Comment: Thank you Arkellys, I admit that I have a ton of structural mistakes, I do not touch code often and that does not help me to keep track and remember these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #91897b;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
 background: #ccb288;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #e8aa45;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background: #f4a11a;
}

img {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:500px;
}

.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 background-color: DodgerBlue;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-grow:1;
}

.flex-container > div {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 width:auto;
 height:100%margin: 1px;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.caja-scroll{
 overflow-y:auto;
 background-color:#fafafa;
 border-color: coral;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 max-width:100%;
  max-height:500px;
  flex-shrink:5;
}

.bordes_gallery {
 border-style:solid;
 max-width:100%;
 flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}

.gallery_item {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 max-height:100px;
 border-style:dotted;
}

.gallery_item > #imagen {
 order: 1;
 flex-basis: 100px;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
}

.gallery_item > #texto {
 order: 2;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 margin-left:5px;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 1263px) {
    .flex-container>div:nth-child(1){width:100%;}
    .flex-container>div:nth-child(1)>img{width:100%;}
    .flex-container {max-width:800px; margin: auto;}

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        <div style="order: 1; flex-basis: content; align-items:center; justify-content:flex-start; display: flex;">
          <img src="http://kb4images.com/images/usa-wallpaper/36955559-usa-wallpaper.jpg"></img>
        </div>
  
        <div style="order: 2; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 28rem; max-height:500px; justify-content:flex-start; flex-shrink: 0;">
            <div class="caja-scroll">
                <div class="col-md-12 bordes_gallery">
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery_item ">
                        <div id="imagen">
                          <img style="max-width:100px;" src="http://www.catolica.edu.sv/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/moodle-200x200.jpg">
                       </div>
                        <div id="texto">asdfadfs</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm trying to get, but in your code the image enlarges horzontally losing its shape. I'd like the picture to keep its aspect ratio and just staying in the center, and the div below getting the width of it, so everything looks like a single column.

Comment: @M.M. check now

Comment: Okay, so I miscalculated dimensions since I'll be using it inside a page of Prestashop, which has a standard size. I edited your last edition in order to add some things more, and when the page is smaller than 1200 it seems to be ok (although I have to fix the pictures), but still wrong in full screen beyond 1200px wide. Here you have it. https://germanmedina.es/content/10-exposicion-vecindario
 could you please tell me what to touch in the inspector in order to make it work?

Comment: in your https://germanmedina.es/themes/MegaShop/assets/css/custom.css ... remove the media query... so instead of @media screen and ( max-width: 1199px) {
.flex-container>div:nth-child(1){width:100%;}
.flex-container>div:nth-child(1)>img{width:100%;}
.flex-container {max-width:666px; margin: auto;}
.segundacaja{width:100%;}
}
... you'll see... 
.flex-container>div:nth-child(1){width:100%;}
.flex-container>div:nth-child(1)>img{width:100%;}
.flex-container {max-width:666px; margin: auto;}
.segundacaja{width:100%;}

Comment: I did this, and now (as you can see if you enter) there is no responsiveness. the boxes should stay on the right of the picture when the windows is bigger than 1200. As you told me, there is always the same format: the format for tablets/phones.

Comment: Hmmm... You may have to change the 1199px then... Some hit and try might help you

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the last 3 days... hit and try... That's why I'm here in search of help...

Comment: Alright. If you see the web as it is now (I'm leaving it for today) it looks pretty close to what I want to achieve. But the second div needs to fill the gap in both screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you Alqbal for all your help (at least one in this big community tried to help me). I worked on the code and I got exactly what I wanted, even with less code.

Comment: @M.M. I am happy that you got what you wanted... Good luck in your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the whole code from scratch and I got working what I wanted. 
Here it is the result.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #91897b;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
 background: #ccb288;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #e8aa45;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background: #f4a11a;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1110px){
.galeria {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style:solid;
   border-color:#45df43;
  max-width:1110px;
 display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
    
}  
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1109px){
.galeria{
 border-style:solid;
   border-color:#45df43;
   max-width:1110px;
   
 display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:center;
}  
  .contenedor_der{
   max-height:490px;
    flex-basis:content;
    width:100%;
    max-width:666px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .contenedor_izq{
    flex-basis:content;
    max-width:666px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 border-style:solid;
   border-color:#df43df;
    flex:1;
    
}
  .contenedor_izq img{
 max-width:666px;
  width:100%;
}
}
.contenedor_izq{
 border-style:solid;
   border-color:#df43df;
   flex-basis:content;
}
.contenedor_izq img{
 max-width:666px;
  flex:1;
}
.contenedor_der{
max-height:416.25px;
overflow-y:scroll;
border-style:solid;
flex:1 1 auto;
}


.caja_articulo{
width:99%; /*Debido a scroll bar que ocupa 10px */
  min-width:auto;
  height:100px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.imagen_articulo{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
.imagen_articulo img{
  max-width:100px;
}
.filas_texto{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left:100px;
  width:auto;
  min-width:100px;
  height:50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#f505d5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Editor JavaScript online - www.cubicfactory.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="galeria">
   <div class="contenedor_izq">
    <img src="http://www.hyattrestaurants.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Collage-800x500px.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor_der">
      <div class="caja_articulo">
          <div class="imagen_articulo">
              <img src="   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Gallet_clamshell_600x600_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja_articulo">
          <div class="imagen_articulo">
              <img src="   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Gallet_clamshell_600x600_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja_articulo">
          <div class="imagen_articulo">
              <img src="   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Gallet_clamshell_600x600_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja_articulo">
          <div class="imagen_articulo">
              <img src="   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Gallet_clamshell_600x600_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="caja_articulo">
          <div class="imagen_articulo">
              <img src="   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Gallet_clamshell_600x600_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
          <div class="filas_texto"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```